# Android - Extract html with tag and make count on result

Tags: android, jsoup, html-parsing

I got a JSON object that return in a long string with html content, 
is there anyway i can get the certain text from this html string and assign put it into textview? what i want to get would probably the content under `<h1>` & `<p>` and throw all others away.

```html
\r\n<div class=\"page-title-wrap sx-hide\">\r\n    
<div class=\"page-title clearfix\">\r\n        
<div class=\"col-lg-12\">\r\n  <h1>Latest Deals</h1>\r\n </div>\r\n  </div>\r\n
</div>\r\n\r\n<div class=\"breadcrumb-wrapper\">\r\n    
<ul class=\"breadcrumb\">\r\n        
<li><a href=\"/Home\">Home</a></li>\r\n        
<li><a href=\"/Deals\">Deals</a></li>\r\n        
<li class=\"active\">Great promotion! Is now RM 95 only!
</li>\r\n    
</ul>\r\n
</div>\r\n\r\n
<div class=\"article outer clearfix\">\r\n    
<div class=\"col-sm-12\">\r\n        
<img alt=\"" title=\"Great promotion! Is now RM 95 only!\" src=\"">\r\n        
<h1>Great promotion! Is now RM 95 only!</h1>\r\n        
<p class=\"date\">March 28th, 2017</p>\r\n        
<p><strong class=\"text-red\"></strong></p>\r\n        
<p>This is the paragraht that shows the description of the promotion deals. You can write anything here.\r\n </p>\r\n        
<p>The buses offered by Alisan Golden Coach are in single deck or double deck. All of the buses are equip with air-conditioning and comfortable seats to ensure passengers are comfortable while travelling on the long journeys.</p>\r\n\r\n        
<p>Book your bus ticket before too late and enjoy the great saving.</p>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n        
<div class=\"m-top30 m-bottom20\">\r\n    
<a href=\"/home\" class=\"btn btn-lg btn-orange\">Home</a>\r\n\r\n    \r\n\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n\r\n
<div id=\"fb-root\"></div>\r\n<script>\r\n    (function(d, s, id) {\r\n      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];\r\n      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;\r\n      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;\r\n      js.async = true;\r\n      js.src = '';\r\n      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);\r\n    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>\r\n\r\n
<div class=\"fb-share-button\" data-href=\"http://google.com/\" data-layout=\"button_count\" data-size=\"large\" data-mobile-iframe=\"true\">\r\n    
<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"" class=\"fb-xfbml-parse-ignore\">Share</a>\r\n</div>\r\n    </div>\r\n</div>
```

basically, the `<h1>` content will assign to "Title" textview and i was think about to take the content from first `<p>` and last `</p>`( the last /p before div class) to put it into a webview as i want to have the paragraph arrangement.

==================== EDIT ==================== 
I had successfully get the content using Jsoup, realize that using the .text() will get all element with the tag and put into a single line, however, i want the result that will maintain the `<p>` format while load into HTML view. Any idea i can do with it?

`Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
 Elements eTitle = doc.getElementsByTag("h1");
 Elements eBody = doc.getElementsByTag("p");
 binding.fragmentWebview.loadData("<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">" + eBody.text(), "text/html; charset=utf-8","UTF-8");`

Comment: Extracting text from tags is pretty basic and there are lots of questions in SO and examples in google. Please edit your question and add the code you've tried.

Comment: yes another way

Answer (score 0):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("String");
Elements pTags = doc.select("p");
int numPTags = pTags.size();
Log.d("pTAG", "P Tagd: " + numPTags);
```

//    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.15.3'